# show and hide form by keyboard c#

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard-hook

I have a form and I want show and hide my form when I press F1, I trying follow this tutorial using Global Low Level Keyboard Hook:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/19004/a-simple-c-global-low-level-keyboard-hook

I press 1x form hides, if I press again show form shortly thereafter it doesn't work.

```
namespace MyForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroForm
    {    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                
        }

        globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F1);
            gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);

            gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);               
        }

       void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
       {
           this.Show();
           e.Handled = true;                
        }

        void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            e.Handled = true;    
        }

        private void Form1_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gkh.unhook();
        }
    }
}
```

thx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing is pressing the button and releasing the button at same time so it will trigger both events at same time instead do something like this

```
public static bool flag = true;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F1);
            gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);

        }

        void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                this.Hide();
                flag = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Show();
                flag = true;
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gkh.unhook();
        }
```

you have to handle it in one event which will be `keydown` because you are pressing `f1` and also i added flag to check if the form is hidden it will show and if form is shown hide it